# SpriteFont not working with MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, monogame, spritefont

```
font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("TopBarFont");
```

For whatever reason no matter what happens, or what I change, I always get this error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

I have TopBarFont.spritefont in the content folder set as content and to always copy to the output directory like all my other assets.

My spritefont file looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XnaContent xmlns:Graphics="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics">
    <Asset Type="Graphics:FontDescription">
        <FontName>Open Sans Light</FontName>
        <Size>36</Size>
        <Spacing>0</Spacing>
        <UseKerning>true</UseKerning>
        <Style>Regular</Style>
        <CharacterRegions>
            <CharacterRegion>
                <Start>&#32;</Start>
                <End>&#126;</End>
            </CharacterRegion>
        </CharacterRegions>
    </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

I saw some other posts to just use a 2d texture and draw that, but just no.. That defaults the whole purpose of using DrawString.

Comment: try adding TopBarFont.xnb into same folder where is .SpriteFont

Comment: MonoGame has a Content builder tool, you should use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xnbbuilder/) converter to convert .SpriteFont into .xnb

Comment: It's kinda unfortunate we have to use a third party tool, but it's okay, it works. And that's what's important. Thanks.